# How can you detect if your React app has been rendered on the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I would like to determine in a component if my React app is building to compare against a checksum or to render normally. Is there a way to have a component behave slightly differently on the initial "checksum" render?

Specifically, I have a component that uses canvas, which the server cannot do. So on the server, I want it to just render up an empty element, and then on the client, match the checksum and subsequently update.

Or is it better, in a case like this, to just let React replace the elements the server rendered with its new ones?

Comment: About rendering canvas on the server, you can use phantomjs  ;)

Answer (score 1):

To check for the environment I use a simple helper function:

```
isBrowser = () => typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.document !== undefined;
```

This works, because `window` and `window.document` are objects specific to the browser. Using this helper you can have behaviour that is specific to browser/server.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking to know if it's server or browser—I'm trying to work out if the browser is running its initial rendering pass to compare to the version generated by the server, or if it's a subsequent pass where it's received new props.

Comment: Could you set a flag in server and then remove that flag in the browser?